# How to detect if two colliders/two triggers are colliding - Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently writing a game that has procedural map generation by spawning prefabs of rooms. These rooms spawn with a "validation" collider. The aim is, if another room/validation collider intersects with another then an output is given. I've tried it with many things, such as OnCollisionEnter2D and OnTriggerEnter2D and yet non of them seem to output anything!

Here's my code

[Validation Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbXTV.png)

And here's the rooms intersecting

[What happens in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRJru.png)

^here it should output something

Just wondering if anyone has an insight into how I could get this to work

Comment: does one of your colliders have a rigidbody componenent attached to it? it says in the unity docs: "Notes: Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached." see here for reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

Comment: How do you move your objects? In general see [Colliders -> Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) also applies to 2D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but this might help find your way:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Intersects.html